# Screen Refresh Issue in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am making an app that uses `firestore`. Whenever a data changes in `firestore` my screen shows two set of data i.e. one set with data before change and other after the change.

for example if I have two data `a,b` and `b` is updated to `c` then the screen shows `a,b a,c`

After toggling between two screen, the screen gets refreshed and things become okay.
How to get the screen show only new set of data

Any help?

```
import  React,{Component} from 'react';
import { View,ScrollView,AsyncStorage, StyleSheet, Dimensions, SafeAreaView,Platform,StatusBar,Text,Alert,Button,FlatList,TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native';
import {db} from "./FirebaseCon.js";
import firebase from "firebase";
import {useNavigation} from "@react-navigation/native";
import "firebase/firestore";
export default class NoticeList extends React.Component
{
  constructor(props)
  {
    super(props);
    this.state={Notice:[],myuser:"",setFlag:null};
  }
  componentDidMount()
  {
      let notice=[];
      var d=new Date();
      var pbm="";
      const notref=db.collection("Notice");
      async:notref.where("expiry",">=",new Date()).orderBy("expiry","desc").onSnapshot(querySnapshot=>
        {
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc=>
                {
                    this.setState({Notice:notice});
                    notice.push(doc.data());
                    this.setState({Notice:notice});
                }
            )
        });

  }

  render()
  {
      const getuser=async()=>
      {
          let uname=await AsyncStorage.getItem("username");
          this.setState({myuser:uname});
          this.setState({setFlag:true});
      }
      if(this.state.setFlag==null)
      {
          getuser();
      }
      let myusername=this.state.myuser;
      return(
        <ScrollView style={nstyles.scene} >
            {
              this.state.Notice.map(data=>{
                  const n1=data.expiry.toMillis()-86400000;
                  const o1=new Date();
                  const p1=new Date(n1);
                  let time=p1.getDate();
                  if(p1.getDate()==o1.getDate())
                  {
                      time="Today, ";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      time="Yesterday, ";
                  }
                  time+=""+p1.getHours();
                  time+=":"+p1.getMinutes();
                  const formtmsg=data.message+"\n\n Published By : \n"+data.pby+"\n\n In Order Of :\n"+data.oby
                  if(data.pby!=myusername)
                  {
                return(
                  <TouchableOpacity style={nstyles.notlist} onPress={()=>Alert.alert("Notice",formtmsg)}>
                   
            <Text style={nstyles.publisher}>{data.oby}<Text style={nstyles.ptime}>{"\n"+time}</Text></Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>);
                  }
              })
      }
      <Text style={{color:"grey",fontSize:16,alignSelf:"center"}}>Published By You</Text>
      {
              this.state.Notice.map(data=>{
                  const n=data.expiry.toMillis()-86400000;
                  const o=new Date();
                  const p=new Date(n);
                  let time=p.getDate();
                  if(p.getDate()==o.getDate())
                  {
                      time="Today, ";
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      time="Yesterday, ";
                  }
                  time+=""+p.getHours();
                  time+=":"+p.getMinutes();
                  const formtmsg=data.message+"\n\n Published By : \n"+data.pby+"\n\n In Order Of :\n"+data.oby
                  if(data.pby==myusername)
                  {
                      return(
                    <TouchableOpacity style={nstyles.notlist2} onPress={()=>Alert.alert("Notice",formtmsg)}>
                     
              <Text style={nstyles.publisher}>{data.oby}<Text style={nstyles.ptime}>{"\n"+time}</Text></Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>);
                  }
              })
      }
        </ScrollView>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your code in a function. Can you show me your code?

Comment: Actually I have used screen navigation(Top Navigation) and the code is part of it

Comment: Can you send me your code? unless its super private

Comment: I have attached the code

Answer (score 0):

Divyansh Dixit, when dealing with lists React uses the `key` prop of the component in order to re-render the screen.

Your issue can be fixed by adding a unique `key` prop to the component returned by your map function, in your case the `<TouchableOpacity>`

It would look something like this

```
 <TouchableOpacity key={data.id}>
     ...
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

You can read more about this on https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: This does not help, it gives the same result on updates